# How do I associate a filetype with an icon?

Tags: c#, registry, file-association

I have written preview handlers for a couple custom file types. These file types don't have an application by default that can open them. I want to associate an icon with the file types as a signifier that they are custom.

I have tried setting a registry entry for `DefaultIcon` in `HKCR\.<filetype>`, but it doesnt appear to work, even after reboots. I do these registry modifications from C#, and the modifications are successful.

The icon file is simply an ico file residing in `%APPDATA%` for the moment. I plan to add a few more icons, and put these in a dll file. I just want to get it to work before I take those next steps.

How can I set this icon?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203755/registering-file-type-and-custom-document-icon-in-net

Comment: I have already looked at that question. He appears to be getting his icons by associating the file type with a program. That is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple .REG file that registers a icon for the file extension .tj

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tj]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.tj\DefaultIcon]
@="D:\\scratch\\testy\\icons\\tj.ico"
```

Tested on Win7

Comment: That looks almost exactly like what I am doing. Are there any size, format constraints? Can the icon live in %appdata% if I give a fully qualified path?

Comment: I believe fully qualified path is necessary, I doubt that %appdata% would work because that translates to a different value for each user.

Comment: Doesn't work on Win10

Answer (score 2):

This [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh127427%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article explains how to assign custom icons to file types

Comment: That is what I initially followed to try and get it to work. What should I call from C# to do the `SHChangeNotify` function? Wouldn't a reboot do the same?

Comment: Should work. However it needs absolute path of the icon as shown by John. Path references like %AppData% doesn't work.

Comment: This MSDN doesn't work