# Unable to set DefaultIcon in registry

Tags: windows, icons, registry, regedit

I am attempting to update the Windows registry to add an icon for my custom file extension, and I have thus far been unsuccessful.  My current version is closest to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8407066/how-do-i-associate-a-filetype-with-an-icon).  Unfortunately, my file's icon is still one of the generic built-in Windows icons (see screenshot below).

[image]

At this point my best guess is perhaps there is something wrong with my `.ICO` file.  I have shared it [here on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/x6owkqvm0o5152z/decrypted.ico?dl=0)

Here is the full registry update I'm making with `regedit`.  As you can see, I am also associating my file extension with a `.bat` file for execution.  That works great.  Also the *Type* displayed in Windows Explorer is *PartQuest Archive* which is also great (see above screenshot).  Alas, no dice with the last entry for the icon.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip]
@="PartQuest Archive"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\MentorGraphics\\PartQuestTools\\SDD_HOME\\common\\win32\\scripts\\pqunzip.bat\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pqz]
@="pqunzip"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pqz\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\MentorGraphics\\PartQuestTools\\SDD_HOME\\common\\win32\\config\\decrypted.ico\""
```

I have also attempted adding a `,1` to the end of the file name since the `.ICO` file appears it may have two icons embedded in it.  This is did not make a difference.

For good measure, I have been rebooting after each change. I'm not certain if this is necessary.

Any tips from the Windows experts around here will certainly be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

So I did a little reverse-engineering to figure out the issue based on 7Zip's file associations.  It turns out that the `DefaultIcon` key entry should be a child of the application, not the file name.  So in my case I need it associated with `pqunzip` rather than `.pqz`:

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\MentorGraphics\\PartQuestTools\\SDD_HOME\\common\\win32\\config\\decrypted.ico\""
```

For maximal clarity, this is the entire contents of my `.req` file that works as expected:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip]
@="PartQuest Archive"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip\shell\open]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\MentorGraphics\\PartQuestTools\\SDD_HOME\\common\\win32\\scripts\\pqunzip.bat\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\pqunzip\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\MentorGraphics\\PartQuestTools\\SDD_HOME\\common\\win32\\config\\decrypted.ico\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pqz]
@="pqunzip"
```