# How to fix: Application Icon overrides File Icon

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10

I have written a WPF application, running on Windows 10. I have two icons: One for the application, one for the associated file type (.rwa). When I install this application I use the register to set the file association, pointing to my File Icon as DefaultIcon. This all works and the shortcut to my application shows the App Icon.
I can double click on a .rwa file Windows asks me what application to use and I select my application. However, as soon as I have done this the file icons change to the application icon!

EDIT: There is extensive information on Microsoft site https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/customizing-file-types-bumper on file types, but they mention *it does not work for Windows 10*, at least after a certain version. Therefore, I am not sure if the changes in the registry I make are correct.
This is what I do:

```
 /// <summary>Makes the association.</summary>
    /// <param name="extension">The extension to associate.</param>
    /// <param name="progID">The program identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="description">The description.</param>
    /// <param name="icon">The full path to the icon.</param>
    /// <param name="application">The name of the application.</param>
    /// <param name="exe">The full path to the executable.</param>
    public static void MakeAssocisation(string extension,
           string progID, string description, string icon, string application, string exe)
    {
        using (var User_Classes = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\", true))
        using (var CurrentVersion = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\", true))
        using (var User_Explorer = CurrentVersion.CreateSubKey("Explorer\\FileExts\\." + extension))
        {
            string applicationPath = application;
            // Register the application
            using (var UserClassesApplications = CurrentVersion.CreateSubKey("App Paths"))
            {
                UserClassesApplications.CreateSubKey(exe).SetValue("", application);
            }
            // Create ProgID
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(progID))
            {
                using (var progId_key = User_Classes.CreateSubKey(progID))
                {
                    progId_key.SetValue("", description);
                    progId_key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", "\"" + icon + "\"");
                }
            }
            // Now the extension
            using (var User_Ext = User_Classes.CreateSubKey("." + extension))
            {
                User_Ext.SetValue("", progID);
                User_Ext.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", "\"" + icon + "\"");
            }
            User_Explorer.CreateSubKey("OpenWithProgids").SetValue(progID, "0");
            using (RegistryKey User_Choice = User_Explorer.OpenSubKey("UserChoice"))
            {
                if (User_Choice != null) User_Explorer.DeleteSubKey("UserChoice");
            }
            SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

When I have made the registry changes I find that the .exe is correctly showing the App Icon and the associated files (.rwa) show the correct icon. If I start the application (e.g., clicking on the short cut) then everything works correctly. However, when I double click a .rwa file I get asked with which application to open (this is what is different in Windows 10; it does not use the association defined in the registry). I select my application and it correctly starts it up but it also changes the icon of my .rwa files!

Comment: looks like its answerd [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203755/registering-file-type-and-custom-document-icon-in-net)

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not give my solution. That post is about getting the file icon in the first places, which works for me. My problem is that the file icon gets replaced. I realize that my question had not enough information, so I have changed it.

Comment: The link you posted is the landing page for the entire section. The section about icons [is this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/how-to-assign-a-custom-icon-to-a-file-type) and hasn't changed all that much since Windows 95. Where did you see that this won't work for Windows 10? Which registry entries did you create?

Comment: The very fact that Windows has to *ask* you which application to use means the registry settings are wrong. By selecting that application you *replaced* the file associations with new ones. I suspect you didn't use a proper MSI installer as file associations are a standard feature

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/shell/fa-sample-scenarios has the remark on Windows 10. The things that changed in Windows 10 is that Microsoft wants us to choose the application on first use.

Comment: I am not using MSI. I am using Squirrel.Windows. I have to update the registry myself for that installer. I added my code in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Panagiotis was right: In my setting of the Register, I missed some information. After some experimentation and by looking at other applications in the registry I came up with the following working code:

```
 /// <summary>Makes the association.</summary>
    /// <param name="extension">The extension to associate.</param>
    /// <param name="progID">The program identifier.</param>
    /// <param name="description">The description.</param>
    /// <param name="icon">The full path to the icon.</param>
    /// <param name="application">The full path to the executable.</param>
    /// <param name="exe">The executable.</param>
    public static void MakeAssociation(string extension,
           string progID, string description, string icon, string application, string exe)
    {
        using (var User_Classes = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\", true))
        using (var CurrentVersion = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\", true))
        using (var User_Explorer = CurrentVersion.CreateSubKey("Explorer\\FileExts\\." + extension))
        {
            // Register the application
            using (var UserClassesApplications = CurrentVersion.CreateSubKey("App Paths"))
            {
                UserClassesApplications.CreateSubKey(exe).SetValue("", application);
            }
            // Create ProgID
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(progID))
            {
                using (var progId_key = User_Classes.CreateSubKey(progID))
                {
                    progId_key.SetValue("", description);
                    using (var command = progId_key.CreateSubKey("shell").CreateSubKey("open").CreateSubKey("command"))
                    {
                        command.SetValue("", "\"" + application + "\" \"%1\"");
                    }
                    progId_key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", "\"" + icon + "\"");
                }
            }
            // Now the extension
            using (var User_Ext = User_Classes.CreateSubKey("." + extension))
            {
                User_Ext.SetValue("", progID);
                User_Ext.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", "\"" + icon + "\"");
            }
            User_Explorer.CreateSubKey("OpenWithProgids").SetValue(progID, "0");
            using (RegistryKey User_Choice = User_Explorer.OpenSubKey("UserChoice"))
            {
                if (User_Choice != null) User_Explorer.DeleteSubKey("UserChoice");
                User_Explorer.CreateSubKey("UserChoice").SetValue("ProgId", progID);
            }
            SHChangeNotify(0x08000000, 0x0000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        }
    }
```

I also found that the path parameters could not include things like %LocalAppData%. It had to be the expanded path.